# Why stack is not at the same address when exec running in GDB

Tags: exploit

During writing some basic challenges, I discover that the exploits are not working if not launched in GDB. To test this behavior, the following program print register values and code address:

```
#include <stdint.h>

intptr_t esp;
intptr_t ebp;

void call_me()
{
  asm("movl %%esp, %0" : "=r" (esp) );
  asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (ebp) );
  printf("call_me: %8x\n", call_me);
  printf("esp: %8x\n", esp);
  printf("ebp: %8x\n", ebp);
}


int main(char *argv[], int argc) 
{
   call_me();    
}
```

When compiled with `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` and running with ASLR disabled (`kernel.randomize_va_space=0`) the program returns:

```
call_me: 804841c 
esp: bffff720
ebp: bffff738
```

But when running inside GDB the program returns:

```
call_me: 804841c
esp: bffff6f0
ebp: bffff708
```

Why the 0x30 differences for $esp and $ebp ? Does GDB add something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is very likely due to differences in the environmental variables of the process when the program is run with `gdb`  compared to when it is run outside of `gdb`. Since environmental variables are stored on the stack, this can affect the memory locations.